# League of Legends crashes on startup in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have tried to install League of Legends on PlayOnLinux in Ubuntu 14.04. My problem is that every time I launch the game, it begins to load, but the bar underneath the logo stops around halfway, and crashes and gives continuous crash logs until I stop the program in the system monitor.

Current specs:
 • AMD FX-8350 CPU
 • Radeon RX 470 8GB Nitro graphics card
 • 16GB HyperX Fury RAM 2133MHz

Comment: What do the logs say? (ring ding ding ding... :p). You may want to try running LOL on vanilla Wine. It works perfectly. See this: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the proprietary graphics driver that you are currently using and install the [AMDGPU-Pro Stack](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) for Radeon RX 480 graphics, Radeon RX 470 graphics and Radeon RX 460 graphics.

#### Installation

1. After the archive is downloaded, extract the contents to a temporary location from which you can install it. The example below assumes you have downloaded the archive to `/tmp` and will extract it to the same location. If your file was downloaded into the `~/Downloads/` folder by default, you can also extract and install from there, and afterwards you can remove the install files.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get upgrade  
   cd /tmp  
   ​tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz
   ```
2. Once the archive is expanded on the local machine, run the included script (amdgpu-pro-install) to install the graphics stack.  During the installation you will be required to provide sudo access, and also to provide two confirmations to:​

   1. Install the package
    2. Allow installation of "unverified" packages from the AMDGPU-PRO archive

   The script will use the package manager to install the components of the graphics stack, with a short delay during the DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) installation. From the directory where you extracted the archive, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
   ```

   Restart your machine to launch using the new graphics stack.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
3. Ensure that your user account is a member of the "video" group prior to using the Vulkan driver. You can find which groups you are a member of with the following command:

   ```
   groups
   ```

   To add yourself to the video group use the following command:

   ```
   compgen -g | grep video # (optional) verify that video group exists 
   sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
   ```

   Log out and in again to activate this change.